# Ways to pass configuration options from node/express server to Vue app without a client-initiated request?

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, webpack, vuex

I have a feeling this may have been asked and answered several times before, but haven't been able to find anything. Probably due to only having super-generic search terms to work with. Anyway:

I've got a Node/Express server which handles some basic/administrative back-end stuff and also serves up a static Vue application, like so, in `app.js`:

```
app.use('/*', express.static('client-dist'))
```

...so the vue app is served whenever express doesn't find a matching route; all other routes are prefixed with `/api`.

I'd like to be able to configure certain aspects of the Vue application via that back-end server at runtime.

At the time the above `app.use` call happens, I've got a plain object called `clientConfig` which has all the information I'd like to pass along to the Vue application, including things like root URLs for API calls and various other things that I want to have available to the client immediately. I'm using vuex, so I'd ideally like to have that object's value plunked into the vuex store upon initial load.

Is there a way to inject that object into Vue, *without* e.g. firing off an axios call as soon as the vue app is loaded to retrieve it? It feels like since the server is what's serving up the vue app, there should be some way to pass it in via e.g. environment variables or something like that, but webpack remains fairly opaque to me so I'm having a hard time coming up with a good way to do it.

Comment: Is Webpack even installed on the server? That should be a *dev* dependency, you're serving the static build output. I've written a bit about SPA runtime config [on my blog](https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html), the SSI option wouldn't require an additional request.

Comment: No, it's just the build output that lives on the server.

Comment: Then Webpack isn't going to be an option, although you can use it at build time (I show one method here: https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/wiki/Client-environment-variables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything that is not dynamically generated at runtime (eg. the api routes), it is best to export them in a json file and include it in your frontend build.

For everything else, I believe your options are limited. The easiest way *is* an ajax call to the server.